# In Azure logic app . I want to check whether emailid which is there in csv file inside blob is present in the table or not

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I need to check whether any emailid which is there in .csv file inside blob present in particular table or not .if no then I need to take some action.
Let me know if anyone knows

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the data from the respective blob and table and compare them using a `Condition` connector. Here is my logic app

[image]

Considering below to be my csv file in azure blob storage

[image]

and below to be my table

[image]

**RESULTS:**

[image]

[image]